# Asymptotic expansion of generalised hypergeometric functions at infinity

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-functions

I am looking for some resources that are available in public domain that have detailed description of the asymptotic expansion of generalised hypergeometric function ${}_pF_q(z)$ at infinity, i.e., $|z|\to \infty$. I have looked on the internet at it seems that there are limited resource on this topic and there are different forms for different relations between $p$ and $q$ namely

1. $p = q + 1$,
2. $p = q$,
3. $p = q-1$ and
4. $p \le q -2$

According to [Wolfram-alpha](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/06/01/05/02/0002/) it seems that the other cases except of $p=q+1$ are not that well [defined](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/06/02/).It would be great if someone can share any resource that has detailed analysis/description of the whole matter as well as discussion on the rest of the cases.

Comment: If $p>q+1$ the series defining ${}_pF_q$ has radius of convergence $0$, so it is not clear how to make sense of your question. The other cases are treated in DLMF, see https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.11